# What is the maximal distance to see a rocket's flare in the sky?

Tags: launch, visibility-of-spacecraft

We get onboard a cruise ship 5 to 6 hours prior to the launch, in direction of Nassau, Bahamas. Cruising at about 25 km/hr, we should be about 150 km away from the pad.Do you think that we still have a reasonable chance to see the rocket's trajectory in the sky at this distance?

Comment: It looks like "as much as 100 miles away" is a pretty commonly quoted figure, so there's definitely a chance you could see it.

Comment: @RussellBorogove I am not sure what rocket is discussed here, but there is a **huge** variation in brightness depending on the propellants. There isn't a standard "rocket brightness". Actually this is an interesting question by itself!

Comment: @RussellBorogove ...and so [have asked thusly](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/20601/12102).