# How to view the Feb 6, 2018 Falcon Heavy launch?

Tags: launch, spacex, falcon-heavy

Will the Feb 6, 2018 SpaceX Falcon Heavy launch from KSC be visible in Boca Raton/ Deerfield Beach area?

Is there a good site for determining viewing ranges for launches?

Comment: That's 178 road miles from Canaveral; if weather is good you may be able to see the exhaust plume.

Comment: Related: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/20505/what-is-the-maximal-distance-to-see-a-rockets-flare-in-the-sky?noredirect=1&lq=1 https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/6555/how-far-away-can-one-see-a-nasa-rocket-launch?noredirect=1&lq=1 https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/20849/how-far-south-can-one-see-a-rocket-launch-from-cape-canaveral-florida?noredirect=1&lq=1